# How can I join 3 separate tables and get the user?

Tags: mysql, sql, nestjs, typeorm

I have 3 tables as below:

Student:

```
id:(PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT),
name:(varchar(100))
```

Notice:

```
   id :(PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)
   Des :varchar(100)
```

NoticeStatus:

```
   id:( PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT )
   noticeId:varchar(100) |  FK  
   studentId:varchar(100) |  FK
```

If any student checks any notice, the row in `NoticeStatus` table with user Id and noticeId is pushed.
How to get all students who don't checked any notice and how can I do this in MySQL or TypeOrm?

Comment: Why would you join 3 tables only 2 appear useful.?

Comment: yep. I only need students name who didn't check notice

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1 from noticeStatus ns where ns.studentId = s.id)
```

This exhibits all students that have no entry in `noticeStatus`.

Comment: thanks @GMB. Just another Quary.If I Have Another Table named User that store user Info and student table only have the userId as FK .How can i get same info by userID from noticestatus table.